# Excel VBA Error when removing duplicate values. Error when running but not when stepping through

Tags: excel, vba

I get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error" when running this entire subroutine when hitting Run Sub (F5).  However when I step through it using debug functions (F8) it passes this line without error.  is there something I can change in the code to correct this.  Code is as follows:

```
lastrow = Sheet9.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Sheet9.Cells(1, 1), Sheet9.Cells(lastrow, 14)).Clear
lastrow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.count, ProjCol).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(i + 1, ProjCol), Sheet3.Cells(i + 1, LampCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Cells(i, 1), Sheet9.Cells(i, 2))
Next i
lastrow2 = Sheet9.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'ERROR OCCURS WITH LINE BELOW
Sheet9.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow2, 2)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: ***ALL*** Range Objects need to have there parents specifically stated: `Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Cells(1, 1), Sheet9.Cells(lastrow2, 2))...`

Comment: That was it, Thanks.  probably worked as I was stepping through because I had the sheet active and was watching it.